# WP8 - How to change MapCartographicMode by selected item

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have got this listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="layerMenu" SelectionChanged="layerMenu_SelectionChanged" >
        <ListBoxItem Content="Road" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Aerial" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="Hybrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="Terrain" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</ListBox>
```

and I would like to change the carthographic mode of my map. Following does not work.

```
private void layerMenu_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{    
     MapCartographicMode selected = (MapCartographicMode)((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem);
     MyMap.CartographicMode = selected;
}
```

This error occures:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

I can solve that by using **switch(layerMenu.SelectedIndex)** but I prefer this shorter way if it is possible.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
MapCartographicMode selected = (MapCartographicMode)((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem);
MyMap.CartographicMode = selected;
```

to this:

```
ListBox listbox = (sender as ListBox)
ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxitem)listbox.SelectedItem;
MapCartographicMode selected = (MapCartographicMode)Enum.Parse(typeof(MapCartographicMode), item.Content.ToString());      
MyMap.CartographicMode = selected;
```